# eclipse juno and jsf 2.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

eclipse won't let me create a project with JSF 2.1 because "Required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder does not exist in selected libraries", but the class does exist.

works well with jsf 2.0.9

Comment: I solved it by moving the JSF 2.1 library outside my project

Comment: So you solved it and answer you question yourself or remove your post.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you may be added your JSF jar file in web-inf/lib folder and after that you add this jar in your jsf configuration.